# How to enable thumbnail view on file dialog boxes?

Tags: nautilus

I find it very inconvenient when I need to upload a file from a folder with A LOT of pictures and I need to inspect each file to find the image I'm looking for.

How do I make file dialog boxes view thumbnails like the way your file manager does?

Basically, from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I hear it's impossible. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

That's called progess ;-) But there is an workable alternative

(if needed) Install dconf-tools
open dconf-editor
Click to: org -> gnome -> nautilus -> list-view
Click (right side of the window) on default-zoom-level keep mouse button pressed for choosing prefered value: standard, large, larger, largest

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. It does change the way the file manager views files though, but not the File Dialog Boxes

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install konqueror`

Yes this `KDE` have many dependencies, but you will have what you want:
[image]

Comment: Many (!) dependencies!!